# How to use @Qualifers for multiple instances of same type with Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2 as DI tool and I have multiple data sources:

local database
remote server
I have following use case:

GetNewspaperUseCase
Now I want to be able to get newspapers from local database and remote server.

I have two qualifers:

- DatabaseQualifer
- NetworkQualifer

Here is Database qualifer:

```
@Qualifier
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface DatabaseQualifer {
 }
```

Here is Network qualifer:

```
@Qualifier
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NetworkQualifer {
}
```

I have module:

```
@Module
public class NewspaperModule {

private GetNewspaperView getNewspaperView;
private DownloadNewspaperView downloadNewspaperView;
private SaveNewspaperView saveNewspaperView;

public NewspaperModule(GetNewspaperView getNewspaperView, DownloadNewspaperView downloadNewspaperView, SaveNewspaperView saveNewspaperView) {
    this.getNewspaperView = getNewspaperView;
    this.downloadNewspaperView = downloadNewspaperView;
    this.saveNewspaperView = saveNewspaperView;
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
@NetworkQualifer
NewspaperDataSource providesDataSource(Retrofit retrofit){
    return new NewspaperNetworkDataSource(retrofit);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
@DatabaseQualifer
NewspaperDataSource providesDatabaseDataSource(AppDatabase appDatabase){
    return new NewspaperDatabaseDataSource(appDatabase);
}


@Provides
@FragmentScoped
NewspaperRepository provideRepository(NewspaperDataSource dataSource){
    return new NewspaperRepositoryImpl(dataSource);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
@NetworkQualifer
GetNewspapersInteractor provideGetNewspaperInteractor(NewspaperRepository repository){
    return new GetNewspapersInteractorImpl(repository);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
@DatabaseQualifer
GetNewspapersInteractor provideGetNewspaperFromDatabase(NewspaperRepository repository){
    return new GetNewspapersFromDatabaseInteractor(repository);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
@NetworkQualifer
GetNewspaperPresenter provideGetNewspaperPresenter(GetNewspapersInteractor interactor){
    return new GetNewspaperPresenterImpl(interactor, getNewspaperView);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
@DatabaseQualifer
GetNewspaperPresenter provideGetNewspaperFromDatabasePresenter(GetNewspapersInteractor interactor){
    return new GetNewspapersFromDatabasePresenter(interactor, getNewspaperView);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
DownloadNewspaperInteractor provideDownloadNewspaperInteractor(NewspaperRepository repository){
    return new DownloadNewspaperInteractorImpl(repository);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
DownloadNewspaperPresenter provideDownloadNewspaperPresenter(DownloadNewspaperInteractor interactor){
    return new DownloadNewspaperPresenterImpl(interactor, downloadNewspaperView);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
SaveNewspaperInteractor provideSaveNewspaperInteractor(NewspaperRepository repository){
    return new SaveNewspaperInteractorImpl(repository);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScoped
SaveNewspaperPresenter provideSaveNewspaperPresenter(SaveNewspaperInteractor interactor){
    return new SaveNewspaperPresenterImpl(interactor, saveNewspaperView);
}
```

}

Here is the code from Component:

```
@FragmentScoped
@Component(dependencies = DataComponent.class, modules =    NewspaperModule.class)
public interface NewspaperComponent {
void inject(NewspaperFragment fragment);
}
```

Now I have Fragment where I am trying to @Inject with @NetworkQualifer, but I get error.

Here is the code from Fragment:

```
@Inject @NetworkQualifer GetNewspaperPresenter getNewspapersPresenter;
```

Here is the error:

> Error:(14, 10) error: at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.domain.newspapers.get.GetNewspapersInteractor cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.domain.newspapers.get.GetNewspapersInteractor is injected at
>   at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.presentation.newspapers.NewspaperModule.provideGetNewspaperPresenter(interactor)
>   @at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.presentation.newspapers.NetworkQualifer at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.presentation.newspapers.get.GetNewspaperPresenter is injected at
>   at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.presentation.newspapers.NewspaperFragment.getNewspapersPresenter
>   at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.presentation.newspapers.NewspaperFragment is injected at
>   at.volksoper.volksoperrefactored.presentation.newspapers.NewspaperComponent.inject(fragment)

Comment: using @Named as suggested here https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide

Comment: The line `GetNewspaperPresenter provideGetNewspaperPresenter(GetNewspapersInteractor interactor)` is wrong, there is no `GetNewspapersInteractor `. You need to use a scoped variant here too, e.g. `provideGetNewspaperPresenter(@NetworkQualifer GetNewspapersInteractor interactor)`